# java script regex 'ç' split 'ç'

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have this array: `['001ç1234567891234çMendonçaç50000', '003ç10ç[1-10-100,2-30-2.50,3-40-3.10]çMendonça']`

I need split it by ç. But I have a problem.

```
  today I have it:  '001' '1234567891234' 'Mendon' 'a' '50000' 
  but I need it: '001' '1234567891234' 'Mendonça' '50000'
```

Comment: Try `/ç(?![a-z])/` (adding more lowercase extended letters can be required)

Comment: What is generating this input? It should escape the delimiter when it is part of a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not quite clear what criterion you want to use for splitting with `ç`, but it is clear that this character may be part of some word and you do not want to break it.

I do not know what language it is, but I think the word cannot end with `ç`, which means there must be a lowercase letter after it. Thus, use a negative lookahead that will fail the match if this letter is followed with another lowercase letter from the language alphabet.

Something like

```js
console.log('001ç1234567891234çMendonçaç50000'.split(/ç(?![a-zç])/))
```

Add more lowercase letters that might appear in your context.

Comment: If it works for you please consider accepting the answer.